# Eclipse EGit: Push just created file

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I just start working with Git. I'm using bitbucket , and i created repo there. I exported my project , and all is fine. Its working , and that is good. I exported it using Commint , and it pushed all files that i need to bit's repo. But now i created new file , and i dont know how to push it.

What is my problem: i clicked Team -> commit -> and there is my problem , before i created file there was 1405 files , and that number didnt change when i created new file. That file is in index , so idk why it didnt see it. And even when i click commits button , it dosent work.
Its saying:

```
An internal error occurred
No changes
```

Oh , btw , i created it in new package. And it dosent see that package too. And i'm using HTTPS connection , if someone needs to know that...

Then i tried workspace sync. , and ... idk how to use that. But sync. does see my changes... 
Soo , is there tutorials how to use git "in right way"? And if there is , can you give link to it? Or what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: just modified alredy created file... and its fine pushed it to bitbucket... Very strange...

Comment: Sounds like the file is ignored, check the `.gitignore` files in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command line or the git_bash.exe (if on windows) and do the following command in the workspace dir of your project:

git add -A -f

git commit -m "commit"

git push

The -f will include files you created separately for the project.

Let me know if that worked